# Converting PHP application to Android

Tags: php, android

I made a website, and used PHP hash functions in the website. Now I want an android app that does the same thing like the website.
Is it possible to make Android app, for android, using PHP? 
I don't need to connect to DB or anything, like I said: I only use the hash function in PHP.

Comment: Not to defend the quality of this question, but your guys' comments are unnecessary and really just rude.

Comment: Actually it took me about a day to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read this [post](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-Android-apps-using-PHP-MySQL) it not a really good idea. If you´re good at Web development maybe you should consider a Hybrid/Cross platform solution instead?

> Hybrid mobile apps are like any other apps you’ll find on your phone.
>   They install on your device. You can find them in app stores. With
>   them, you can play games, engage your friends through social media,
>   take photos, track your health, and much more.
>   Like the websites on the internet, hybrid mobile apps are built with a
>   combination of web technologies like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Google for Hybrid applications and Cross platform applications and check out the frameworks below:

- Ionic
- Appcelerator Titanium
- Sencha Touch
- PhoneGap

Comment: "hybrid mobile apps are built with a combination of web technologies like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript." . Does it also support php?

Comment: Yes you could also include PHP, the frameworks supports webdevelopment. I have used Titanium with PHP and can recommend it. @jaldk